# Bootstrap col-md-6 gives different heights

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The code below should give me 2 content blocks next to each other on the same level of height and when you resize your window it should be 1 content block.
But when I run this it gives me 2 content blocks but the right one is not on the same level as the first one. It dropped like 80px (can't give you a picture to see it).

How's that possible I use this for over a year and nothing happened like this and it's not changing when I rewrite everything.

```html
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <h2>De zorg die u en u geliefde verdienen</h2>
                    Zo heeft u de keuze uit tal van mogelijkheden om uw eigen uitvaartdienst of die van uw familie voor te bereiden, op te volgen en te laten uitvoeren naar uw eigen wensen en inzichten.<br>
    Door onze jarenlange ervaring staan wij garant voor verzorgde en stijlvolle uitvaarten. Wij houden ons ter beschikking met de waardigheid en discretie waarop u en uw dierbaren recht hebben.<br>
    De Ruyte Uitvaartzorg handelt vanuit het respectvolle idee van voorzorg, zorg en nazorg. Op die manier krijgt u de ondersteuning die nodig is in ieder stadium van het serene afscheid.
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    Zo heeft u de keuze uit tal van mogelijkheden om uw eigen uitvaartdienst of die van uw familie voor te bereiden, op te volgen en te laten uitvoeren naar uw eigen wensen en inzichten.<br>
    Door onze jarenlange ervaring staan wij garant voor verzorgde en stijlvolle uitvaarten. Wij houden ons ter beschikking met de waardigheid en discretie waarop u en uw dierbaren recht hebben.<br>
    De Ruyte Uitvaartzorg handelt vanuit het respectvolle idee van voorzorg, zorg en nazorg. Op die manier krijgt u de ondersteuning die nodig is in ieder stadium van het serene afscheid.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you put a red border on `col-sm-12` and post a screenshot, im not sure what you mean

Comment: this is how it looks for me http://we.tl/8fBRVvxZYT

Comment: Have you tried an inspector tool? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnWL2d9bGPk (Your screenshot showed Safari. I'd recommend Chrome for this purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site (from the screenshot URL) and there is an id on the second coumn (second-column) which has responsive classes that add a top margin of 25px / -25px depending on the size of the screen.

This would cause the divs not to line up.

Comment: I added that so it will be the same height, cuz i'm just gone fix it with media queries I think that's the easiest way and also the fastest. But thank you for looking.